# Locating dropdown box using Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate the drop down box using C# in selenium webdriver. Tried with different 
option like By.Id, By.XPath, But unable to locate the element. Below is the HTML code for 
the same.

```
<div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 387px; top: 32px;">
<div class="chzn-search">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 352px;" tabindex="5">
</div>
<div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto;">
    <ul class="chzn-results" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto;">
    <div class="slimScrollBar" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0);  width: 15px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 0.4; display: block; border-radius: 7px; z-index: 99; right: 1px; height: 121.263px;"></div>
        <div class="slimScrollRail" style="width: 15px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: block; border-radius: 7px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 51, 51); opacity: 0.2; z-index: 90; right: 1px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which xpath expressions have you tried?

Comment: Please post the code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try By.Css, e.g.

```
driver.find(By.Css(".slimScrollDiv"));
```